# How to create a horizontally scrollable flex column of reversed flex rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I want to create a horizontally scrollable flex column which holds several flex rows, however each row I want to display in a reversed fashion. i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6 displays as 6,5,4,3,2,1.

Here is a JSFiddle of my attempt:

https://jsfiddle.net/6kjgdtas/

As you can see the horizontal scrollbar disappears.

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

I expect a horizontally scrollable column of two rows, displaying 6,5,4,3,2,1 (i.e. reverse order), where each div is display: flex

Comment: _“As you can see the horizontal scrollbar disappears.”_ - because you neglected to allow your flex items to _wrap_, so both of your “rows” get displayed on one line. Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.column`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As you can see the horizontal scrollbar disappears.

That happens because you neglected to allow your flex items to *wrap*, so both of your “rows” get displayed on one line.

Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.column`, to allow the elements to wrap if required:

```
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this format of code.

```css
.column{
  display:flex;
  overflow:auto;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

.box{
  display:flex;
  background: red;
  margin:2px;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:50px;
  padding:5px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```